# Adding Tabs and Pages to Ionic Project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm very new to angular and ionic, as in this is my first little project.

I'm having problems creating a route that pulls json from a different source.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')

        $stateProvider.state('app.event.detail', {
            url: '/:event',
            templateUrl: 'event.html',
            controller: 'EventCtrl'
        })

    })

    myApp.controller('EventCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.todos = [
            {title: "Take out the trash", done: true},
            {title: "Do laundry", done: false},
            {title: "Start cooking dinner", done: false}
        ]
    })

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($http) {
        var main = this;
        //debugger
        $http.get('http://call.amir-meshkin.com/call-for-entries/').success(function(data){
            //debugger
            main.items = data;
            console.dir(data);
        })


    });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/UYgOwC1nqUrpG45wR4q4

Comment: can you be more specific? Not really clear on what is not working

Comment: All I am trying to do is have one page called calls and another called galleries, with a tab representing each page.  Each page just pulls data from another remote json file.

Trying to do things in js that I used to do in php is a bit strange